# How do I write a request spec to test user login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to write a spec to test my user_login API, but keep getting the JSON email/password  incorrect error `401` when I run the spec. I'm doing the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  subject(:user) do
    Program.create!(name: 'test', gender: 'Female', goal_id: '1', experience_id: '1')
    User.create!(email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678', goal_id: '1', experience_level_id: '1', gender: 'Female')
  end

  it "is logged in" do
    post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678' }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 1

Here is my sessions_controller, which is being used when a user logs in via the API.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:create, :destroy]
    before_filter :ensure_params_exist
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user_login][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user_login][:password])
        sign_in("user", resource)
        resource.ensure_authentication_token!
        render 'api/v1/sessions/new.json.jbuilder', status: 201
        return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end

  def destroy
        current_user.reset_authentication_token
        render json: {success: true}
  end

  protected

  def ensure_params_exist
    return unless params[:user_login].blank?
    render json: {success: false, message: "missing user_login parameter"}, status: 422
  end

  def invalid_login_attempt
    render 'api/v1/sessions/invalid.json.jbuilder', status: 401
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help if you post your login controller

Comment: I'd check your log output to make sure it's reaching that controller action, then start using the [debugger](http://rubydoc.info/gems/debugger/1.6.2/frames) or `puts`s to see that the params that you expect are actually coming in.

Comment: How do I check my log output? Nothing happens in the server output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was very close, and maybe that is why I was having so much trouble. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "sessions" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:program)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  describe "user" do
    it "is logged in" do
  post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: @user.email, password: @user.password }

      response.status.should be(201)
    end
  end
end
```

I switched the `subject` block for a `before` block, and used instance variables for the email and password. That's it!